# Linux MySql Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, linux, jar

I have the following problem. I have a Server on  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-23-generic x86_64) and connect via SSH client (Putty).

I have Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11) installed.

I have MySql server installed:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper.

I have a user with following grants:
[grants screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFwKr.png)

and I have the following hibernate.cfg.xml: [hibernate.cfg.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KcmQ.png)

I run my jar file with this configuration and obtain the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'SuperUser'@'localhost' to database 'cryptoprojectdb'
```

Before this I have run this jar on Windows with v. 8.0.11 MySql Community Server - GPL with the same user and have no problems.

Please, advice!

Comment: Have you flushed privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux MySQL database names and table names are case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works. That was the difference between Windows and Linux